# Am i iterating through querySelectorAll, incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently attempting cs50 lab 8. It's split into two parts. While I've gotten no issue with part one, my code isn't working at all for part two. I'm supposed to allow the user to enter some text for a trivia question and state whether their answer is correct or not. It's optional to have more than one question. A single question worked fine but for practice, I added more and nothing happens when i click the submit button.

```
<script>
     let fResponse=document.querySelectorAll('.freeResponse');
                for(let j = 0; j < fResponse.length; j++){
                    fResponse[j].addEventListener('click',()=>{
                        let fAnswer=fResponse[j].querySelector("input");
                        if(j == 0){
                            let response=document.querySelector('#f1');
                            if(fAnswer.value=="Massachusetts"){
                                    response.innerHTML="<h3><i>Correct!</i></h3>";
                            }
                            else{
                                response.innerHTML="<h3><i>Incorrect!</i></h3>";
                            }
                        }
                        else if(j == 1){
                            let response=document.querySelector('#f2');
                            if (fAnswer.value=="8"){
                                response.innerHTML="<h3><i>Correct!</i></h3>";
                            }
                    }
                    }); 
<div class="section">
                <h2>Part 2: Free Response</h2>
                <hr>
                <h3>In what state is Harvard Univeristy located?</h3>
                <form>
                    <input type="text">
                    <button class="freeResponse" type="button">Submit</button>
                    <p id= f1></p>
                </form>

                <h3>How many planets are there in our solar system?</h3>
                <form>
                    <input type="text">
                    <button class="freeResponse" type="button">Submit</button>
                    <p id= f2></p>
                </form>

``
```

Comment: `fResponse[j].querySelector("input")` will try to find a input child element of your button, but your button has no child elements (your input is a sibling not a child of the button). Therefore your `fAnswer` variable will be `undefined`  and there should be an error being generated when you try to do `fAnswer.value`

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors in the log but when I print out fAnswer to the log, it's blank so i guess that does mean it isn't getting a value. I guess my question should be, how do I access a specific query from querySelectorAll?

Comment: you are a missing a `}` in your code that would mean it won't even parse let alone run - check the browser *developer* tools for errors

Comment: Okay i figured it out. If i change it to:
let fAnswer=document.querySelectorAll("input")[j]
It works fine and i'm able to iterate everything without any visible issue. Thanks for your assistance

As for the missing brackets, they're missing from copy/pasting/editing. It's there in the code I'm working on